# Ansible: ec2_eni cannot attach interface

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, network-interface

Using ansible I am trying to create ec2 instances and attach an extra network interface to each instance so that they will have two private IP addresses.  However, for some reason, it seems that the [ec2_eni](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_eni_module.html) module can create network interfaces, but will not attach them to the instances specified. What am I doing wrong?  Below is my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Create new servers
      ec2:
        region: "{{ region }}"
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{ subnet }}"
        group_id: "{{ sec_group }}"
        assign_public_ip: yes
        wait: true
        key_name: '{{ key }}'
        instance_type: t2.micro
        image: '{{ ami }}'
        exact_count: '{{ count }}'
        count_tag:
          Name: "{{ server_name }}"
        instance_tags:
          Name: "{{ server_name }}"
      register: ec2

    - name: Show ec2 instance json data
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ec2['tagged_instances'] }}"

    - name: allocate new elastic IPs and associate it with instances
      ec2_eip:
        region: "{{ region }}"
        device_id: "{{ item['id'] }}"
      with_items: "{{ ec2['tagged_instances'] }}"
      register: eips

    - name: Show eip instance json data
      debug:
        msg: "{{ eips['results'] }}"

    - ec2_eni:
        subnet_id: "{{ subnet }}"
        state: present
        secondary_private_ip_address_count: 1
        security_groups: "{{ sec_group }}"
        region: "{{ region }}"
        device_index: 1
        description: "test-eni"
        instance_id: "{{ item['id'] }}"
      with_items: "{{ ec2['tagged_instances'] }}"
```

The strange thing is that the ec2_eni task succeeds, saying that it has attached the network interface to each instance when in reality it just creates the network interface and then does nothing with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As best I can tell, since [`attached` defaults to `None`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.6.3/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2_eni.py#L564), but [the module docs say](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.6.3/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2_eni.py#L63-L64):

> Specifies if network interface should be attached or detached from instance. If ommited, attachment status won't change

then [the code does what they claim](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.6.3/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2_eni.py#L322) and skips the attachment step.

This appears to be a bug in the documentation, which [claims the default is 'yes'](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.6.3/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2_eni.py#L65) but is not accurate.

Comment: I've started the process to fix the docs: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/44523

Comment: Thanks, I added `attached: yes` and it will now attach the extra interface.

Comment: I did notice another bug where if I specify that I want my `secondary_private_ip_address_count: 2` or value greater than 1 (which t2.micro instances dont support) I recieve the error `"msg": "Network interface 'eni-asdfagibberishadsf' is currently in use."` instead of saying that the extra interface cannot be attached due to ec2 type restrictions.  It then proceeds to attach the interface despite this error adding only one of the two extra private ips on the interface.

Comment: Can you please open an ansible issue about that t2.micro problem? I don't know if that error state is something they can distinguish from the AWS API, but it can't hurt to ask

Comment: Ok ill open a new issue.